# Suppress Gradle Warning in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I get the following warning in Android Studio:

```
Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20140107 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
```

I cannot remove the dependency because I use it in a dependent project.

**How can I suppress the above Gradle Warning in Android Studio?**

Comment: Why bother having this dependency in the first place, if it's not going to be used? Are you requesting this dependency yourself, or is it some transitive dependency you are getting by requesting some other library?

Comment: Just remove `org.json:json`. You are not using it. Android has it's own `org.json:json`. It has the same class and package names.

Comment: I use it in a dependent project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be sufficient enough for all of your needs:

```
compile ('some:project:or:library'){
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to exclude files in the dependent project?

Comment: Why would you like to do such a thing? And also, what kind of files?

Comment: I want to exclude A File MYGWT.java. Because it is GWT only.

Comment: Maybe you could try with -injars method in ProGuard (I'm not sure), but is it really worth it? It's just one class and you can always shrink it with Proguard, so keeping it is a zero cost for you.